# How to download a page in swift2 without using third party libraries?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, download, swift2

I am trying to show the downloaded HTML page in the app. Please explain the simplest way to do so without using any third party libraries.

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can show a html page in app without downloading

```
 let pageUrl = NSURL (string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
 let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
```

if you want to show a local file you show like this

```
let htmlfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("filename", withExtension: "html");
    let req = NSURLRequest(URL: htmlfilePath !);
    webview.loadRequest(req);
```

to download a file you can use plain NSURLSession

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am looking for a way to do it by downloading the page and then using it .

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL to download your website data asynchronously:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let stackoverflowLink = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315798/how-to-download-a-page-in-swift2-without-using-third-party-libraries"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadHTML()
    }

    func loadHTML() {
        guard let url = URL(string: stackoverflowLink) else  { return }
        print("LOADING URL")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let htmlCode = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) // make sure you use the correct String Encoding
            else { return }
            print(htmlCode)
            print("URL LOADED")
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can download a web site directly into an NSData object as in this example (Objective-C);

```
    NSURL *tutorialsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials"];
    NSData *tutorialsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tutorialsUrl];
```

Swift example;

```
    let aString = "http://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t31.0-8/q88/s720x720/10848858_907722502601079_2834541930671169073_o.jpg"
    let url = NSURL(string: aString)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
```

Ray has a great tutorial here;

https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios