# Cannot get contents of URL

Tags: swift, nsurl, core-foundation

So I have the following URL:

```
let theURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.iana.org/domains/example")!
```

But all I get after running:

```
let blob : String
do {
    blob = try String(contentsOfURL: theURL)
}
catch {...}
```

Is a console statement that reads as follows:

> CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme

The URL is valid, and the code works with:

> http://www.example.com

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36322323/2303865

Comment: Ideally I can do this using String(contentsOfURL: _) ; Is my URL improperly encoded?

Comment: you should never download any data synchronously

Comment: Very well. Using the method described in the linked discussion, the url should work?

Comment: You can download any kind of data using NSURLSession. What you mean should work? BTW you need also to edit your info plist and add the thrusted domain or use https

Comment: make sure you are using the correct String encoding

Comment: Yep, I edited the ATS. The string encoding is what I was asking about.

Comment: You should use String(contentsOfURL:) only to load local text files, not network requests

Answer (score -1):

Here's a cleaner version of what you're trying to do.

```
let theURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.iana.org/domains/example")!

let blob : String

do {
  blob = String(theURL)
}
catch { }
```

Corrections:

1. theURL is an optional that was still wrapped that's why you couldn't assign it.
2. You misused contentsOfURL
3. If you're immediately assigning the variable you don't need to declare it the way you did

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if you provide me with more information I can better answer your question.

Comment: Correct, that assignment was mostly for the question (it is slightly different in the program) I will make an edit accordingly ; contentsOfURL is correct for what I am doing (I don't need it to be asynchronous) ; The object is to get the html contents of a given URL.